# gcc compiler error <memory>

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, g++, mingw

I am learning about smart pointers and when compiling I got the following error.

This is my class and for experimentation I added a vector of std::unique_ptr type. However, after doing so I get the error message

```
class TreeNode {

public:
    using node_ptr=std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>;
    float totValue = 0;
    float nVisits = 0;
    uint8_t move;
    HexBoard* board;
    std::vector<TreeNode> children;
    //added this
    std::vector<node_ptr>test;
    void calculateIteration(Union unionF);
    uint8_t select();
    uint8_t selectBestMove();
    bool isLeaf();
    void expand();
    void update(float value);

};
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/memory:64:0,
                 from C:\Users\Robin\source\repos\HexVC++\HexVC++\TreeNode.h:6,
                 from C:\Users\Robin\source\repos\HexVC++\HexVC++\HexVC.cpp:4:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode, std::default_delete<TreeNode> >&}]':
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>]'
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> >]'
C:\Users\Robin\source\repos\HexVC++\HexVC++\TreeNode.h:21:7:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = TreeNode; _Dp = std::default_delete<TreeNode>]'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/memory:80:0,
                 from C:\Users\Robin\source\repos\HexVC++\HexVC++\TreeNode.h:6,
                 from C:\Users\Robin\source\repos\HexVC++\HexVC++\HexVC.cpp:4:
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/X86_64~2.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\HexVC++.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/HexVC++.dir/HexVC.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/HexVC++.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/HexVC++.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: HexVC++] Error 2
```

What does this error mean ?

Comment: @xskxzr edited the question

Comment: Someone is trying to copy a `unique_ptr`, possibly inside a vector. And a `unique_ptr` cannot be copied, because then it wouldn't be unique.

Comment: @BoPersson hmm so I would need to move instead of "copy", right ? However, the vector I added is just a dummy, nothing is being done to it at all. So why do I still get the error msg ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to move it if you want to relocate it. Possibly the vector is copied as part of the containing class, somewhere in HexVC.cpp?

Comment: @BoPersson I think, that solves it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe because `HexBoard` is an *incomplete type*. Does it work when you replace `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr`?

Comment: .... you really need to learn to read error messages ... it's written in English, not machine code ...

Comment: There's something you're not showing us. Does TreeNode have a destructor? There's something preventing the generation of the move constructor. Please provide a MCVE.